# Is Javascript correct with bootstrap-multiselect in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a multiselect dropdown menu witht the bootstrap-multiselect plugin in Django 1.4.5. Link to plugin: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

My form.py is:

```
weight_training_days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    help_text=u'(Required) Select 3 days',
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'inline': True,
        'class': 'multiselect',
    }),
    choices=(
        (0, "Mon"),
        (1, "Tue"),
        (2, "Wed"),
        (3, "Thu"),
        (4, "Fri"),
        (5, "Sat"),
        (6, "Sun"),
    ),
)
```

My form in the template is:

```
<form class="form-{{ layout }}" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form|as_bootstrap:layout }}

    <p class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes" class="btn btn-primary">
    </p>
</form>
```

And the js code in the bootstrap-multiselect.js file (which is linked to in the static folder):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.multiselect').multiselect({
     buttonClass: 'btn',
     buttonWidth: 'auto',
     buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-group" />',
     maxHeight: false,
     buttonText: function(options) {
       if (options.length == 0) {
         return 'None selected <b class="caret"></b>';
       }
       else if (options.length > 3) {
         return options.length + ' selected  <b class="caret"></b>';
       }
       else {
         var selected = '';
         options.each(function() {
           selected += $(this).text() + ', ';
         });
         return selected.substr(0, selected.length -2) + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

For some reason the plugin is not working. Only a standard SelectMultiple field is presented.

I have very limited experience with javascript and am not sure why this plugin won't work. Any feedback/assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to my inexperience/knowledge of javascript. I need to download the library for this plugin and that is what went in the bootstrap-multiselect.js file. Works great now.