# How to create a form with sticky tag similar to that of adding tags to Stack overflow's in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

There is a feature on Slack that allows you search for a user when you want to send a direct message and clip it. It's also similar to the way tags are added when filling out a question on StackOverflow--what is it called? How can one add this feature to a Django form? Can it be added to for a ForeignKey field or only a ManyToMany Field?

Comment: I don't think there's any default way of doing this. You could try something like this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093605/is-javascript-correct-with-bootstrap-multiselect-in-django

Comment: What of django taggit?